# How to hide parent div if tr is empty with thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, css, thymeleaf

I am using the thymeleaf framework. I wanted to hide the whole div if values are coming out as empty. and show if it's not null.

**Html code**

```
<div>
<h2> My Table </h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="powderblue">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>hobby</th>
            <th>interest</th>
            <th>books</th>
            <th>movie</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="table: ${myTable}">

        <td th:text = "${table.name != null ? table.name : 'NULL'}" />
        <td th:text = "${table.age != null ? table.age : 'NULL'}" />
        <td th:text = "${table.hobby != null ? table.hobby : 'NULL'}" />
        <td th:text = "${table.interest != null ? table.interest: 'NULL'}" />
        <td th:text = "${table.books != null ? table.books : 'NULL'}" />
        <td th:text = "${table.movie != null ? table.movie : 'NULL'}" />

        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

How can I hide this div when "tr th:each="table: ${myTable}" is not displaying any values? It does not have to be strictly thymeleaf function. I can use angularjs functions if possible.

**Confusion**

I was thinking to do something like if tr tag is null hide div. But my first tr tag wouldn't be null since it is static.

**Output**

```
My Table
|name | age | hobby | interest | books | movies |
|     |     |       |          |       |        |
```

How can I hide the whole if the values are null/empty? Table values varies and obtained by a database. Sometimes can be blank sometimes has values

Comment: check if myTable is empty or not, this is really trivial

Comment: I got confused with my own naming convention, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you using Thymeleaf version 3.x.x, this it will help you:

```
<div th:if="${!myTable.isEmpty()}">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better approach would be [usage of the `lists` utility](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-lists-utility#empty)

```html
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(myTable)}">
  ...
</div>
```